# Can we submit separate ARM6 and ARM7 Universal binaries to appstore?

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store

Our app is 13.3MB in size and over 20MB after submission (22.8MB to be precise after stripping everything back as much as possible). It is a universal binary (iPad/iPhone) and compiled as a fat binary (ARM6/ARM7).

If I build only ARM6 or ARM7 it will be 10MB and squeeze under the 20MB submission size.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should compile for `armv6` only if you want to support pre-`iPhone 3GS`, but you can happily compile `armv7` for `iPhone 3GS`/`iPhone 4`/`iPad`/`iPad 2` support. You can't submit two binaries for the same application, though. You have to choose one or the other.

Alternatively, if you can extract some of the image or audio/video resources from the app and put them on a webserver somewhere, you can then make your app fetch and cache them to the disk at first start. That way, you'll be able to submit a fat binary, but it'll still also have access to all of the app's resources.

Comment: Thanks. Our customer still wants to support iPhone3G - but the compiled exe grows by 3.3MB with it. We have stripped out everything we can. Ideally I'd move files to a webserver - but we need to submit today and we don't want add new code in to the app which is currently tested and stable.

Comment: .. you did leave it a bit late to ask a StackOverflow question on the same day you have to submit the app, then. Well, the only thing I can suggest is to very quickly bundle in [`ASIHTTPRequest`](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest), which is an already fully functional library and caches resources for you (you can set the cache mode to keep forever). Good luck!

Comment: (... yes late, but the app was just released this morning and we discovered over 20MB. As our customer has a public event coming up soon, they need a reliable solution today to submit again and get it out in time.) Any way, thanks for your suggestion, we already have Async HTTP support in the code, but I don't think I can get the size down even with off loading everything to a server. After analysing the app (A Unity based app) only 3MB are actual visual/sound assets. But we will submit a ARM7 app, and then look and see if your suggestion may work for us. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Apple may no longer be accepting armv6-only binaries, as those were for pre-iOS3.x, which Apple states that they no longer accept.

Comment: `armv6` is a hardware revision, and they still provide support for the `iPhone 3G` as far as I know, which uses an `armv6` processor. As long as they officially support the `3G`, you can compile for `armv6`.

Comment: Note that by 'support', I don't mean new iOS versions. I mean technical support and product repairs.